# How do I make sure that a refresh token is returned by Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory library?

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory

Specifically is there any way to check if `AuthenticationContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync()` successfully obtains a refresh token?

Comment: You want to await the result, then check the return value `Task` for the access token. Check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identitymodel.clients.activedirectory.authenticationcontext.acquiretokenbyauthorizationcodeasync?view=azure-dotnet

Comment: @hmiedema9 I need to know about the *refresh token* not the access token.

Comment: It should always return one. Have you run into a case where this was not the case? ADAL handles refresh tokens internally, they are not shown to you. If you want to persist tokens across process restarts then you'll need to implement a TokenCache and give that to the context whenever you create a context.

Comment: And you don't need the refresh token, you can ask for tokens from ADAL and it'll use the refresh token if the access token is expired.

Answer (score 0):

Azure AD Authentication Library (ADAL) relies on its token cache for efficient token management. When you request an access token with AcquireTokenSilentAsync and there is a valid token in the cache you get it right away. Otherwise if there is a refresh token it's used to obtain a new access token from Azure AD. The new token is then written into the cache and returned to you.

The library itself supports all kinds of scenarios: from mobile and JavaScript clients to server side applications. It can be used to store tokens for a single user as well as for many users. If you look at the token cache key class you can see that tokens can be stored and queried by target resources and authorities in addition to clients (applications) and users.

You don't directly work with the cache key and the underlying dictionary. Instead, you properly construct the AuthenticationContext and pass other parameters such as client credentials, user and/or resource identifiers to various AcquireToken* methods.

By default, there is an in memory singleton cache which is good for quick testing but it doesn't work in real life scenarios. First, tokens have their lifetime and if your application gets restarted you lose them and the user will have to re-authenticate against Azure AD. Second, when you scale out you need to make the cache available to all instances of your application.

The way the cache supports external storage basically boils down to the following. You derive from TokenCache and provide handlers for BeforeAccess and AfterAccess events. These are not even events technically, you just provide a couple of delegates. BeforeAccess gets called every time ADAL wants to access the cache and this is where you get a chance to populate the cache from your external storage. AfterAccess is called at the end of AcquireToken* methods and you want to persist the cache if it has been modified which you can tell by examining the HasStateChanged property. Pretty straight forward.

Now, when you load or persist the cache, that includes the whole dictionary, not just individual items. You are provided with convenient Serialize and Deserialize methods so you don't have to worry about they structure of keys and values. Instead, you just persist byte arrays.

That means, in server side web applications you want to manage the cache by users.

You can choose whatever the external storage and data access technology. In ASP.NET Core it makes a whole bunch of sense to make use of IDistributedCache as you get SQL Server and Redis support out of the box.

For further reference please browse:

[adal-distributed-token-cache-in-asp-net-core](https://dzimchuk.net/adal-distributed-token-cache-in-asp-net-core/)